How to Tell Apart Transforming from Modal Double Faced Cards
Transforming and modal double faced cards function quite differently; only the front side of TDCFs can be played, and MDCFs can't transform.
Usually it's pretty obvious whether a DFC is transforming or modal:

They have differently shaped icons in the top corner
TDFCs always (so far) transform themselves, or exile and return transformed
MDFCs have a 'snippet' of the other side at the bottom left of each side

But what is the canonical way to tell them apart?

Rule 712.3a-c say

712.3a A modal double-faced card’s front face is marked by a front-face symbol in its upper left corner. The front-face symbol is a single black triangle inside a sideways teardrop.
712.3b A modal double-faced card’s back face is marked by a back-face symbol in its upper left corner. The back-face symbol is two white triangles inside a sideways teardrop.
712.3c Each face of a modal double-faced card includes a hint bar in the lower left corner with information about the opposite face. This is reminder text and has no effect on game play.

These are the features that distinguish modal double-faced cards. The features of transforming double-faced cards are correspondingly described in rule 712.2a-c in the same section. The hint bar at the bottom is probably the most consistently noticeable of those listed features.
